# Require time zone in type="xs:dateTime"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Is it possible to somehow require a time zone in a `dateTime` in XML Schema?

Comment: If you have modified `xs:dateTime`, please show (at least) that part of your XSD.

Comment: @MathiasMüller No, no, it is not actually modified, I just assumed that it needs to be modified :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To require a `xs:dateTime` to have a timezone, add `xs:pattern` facets to a `xs:restriction`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="dateTimeWithRequiredTimeZone">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
      <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\dZ"/>
      <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\+\d\d:\d\d"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**Edit**:
As Michael Kay helpfully points out, the above patterns **overspecify the requirements**.  Just like `xs:dateTime` checking will already have restricted the digits per date and time constraints, it will also have restricted that they *be* digits.  Therefore the pattern can attend only to the added length of a time-zoned `xs:dateTime`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="dateTimeWithRequiredTimeZone">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
      <xs:pattern value=".{20}.*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Also per Michael: XSD 1.1 has `explicitTimeZone="required|prohibited|optional"`

Comment: Oh, I missed that there can be multiple patterns. Second pattern should be "\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\+\d\d:\d\d" - we need to escape this "+" :) . Thanks!

Comment: In XSD 1.1 there's a specific facet: `explicitTimeZone=required | prohibited | optional`. The pattern given restricts the timezone to be a positive displacement. It's also unnecessarily precise: `value=".{20}.*"` works just as well.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Ah, yes, why not fully leverage the checking already done by `xs:dateTime`?  Good point.

Comment: The pattern requiring just 20 characters or more can be fulfilled by just adding a seconds fraction which is allowed in `xs:dateTime`. Also, the pattern for numeric timezone offset specification allows only for "+", not "-". Therefore, I'd choose `<xs:pattern value=".+Z"/>
      <xs:pattern value=".+(\+|-)\d\d:\d\d"/>`

Comment: I was wondering about the 20. Do I read correctly that you have 22 or more characters, and this is the shortest example? 2022-05-30T09:30+06:00.

Comment: There is a problem with the pattern check for at least 20 characters: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime specifies that partial seconds are also allowed. This would satisfy the length check without a time offset being specified. I would also like to note that there actually is a difference between a time offset and a time zone. The former might change in offset for summer and winter time. The latter is a time zone with it's summer/winter time rules. XSD dateTime only allows for a time offset to be added.

Comment: <xs:pattern value=".*(Z|[+-][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})"/>